# Group by to list multiple cols without nan (or any value)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Please note this is just an example, there are more columns in the example and the list ends up being very big, hence I don't want to iterate it twice**

Having:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Peter','Peter','Anna','Anna','Anna'],
                     'Country1':['Italy',np.nan,np.nan,'Sweden',np.nan],
                     'Country2':[np.nan,'Venezuela',np.nan,'Peru','Iceland'],
                     'Price':[12,33,45,6,9]})
```

I do

```py
data_g_name = data.groupby('Name')
country_cols=['Country1','Country2']
g_stats = pd.DataFrame({
    'Countries':data_g_name['Country1','Country2'].apply(lambda x:x.values.flatten().tolist()),
    'TotalCost' : data_g_name['Price'].sum()
})
```

And obtain:

```
'    Name                               Countries  TotalCost
0   Anna  [nan, nan, Sweden, Peru, nan, Iceland]         60
1  Peter            [Italy, nan, nan, Venezuela]         45'
```

**I would like (without having to iterate through the list if possible, real case list is big):**

```
     Name           Countries        TotalCost
0    Anna            [Sweden,Peru,Iceland]          60
1    Peter           [Italy,Venezuela]           45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) to unpivot dataframe, drop all row with `NaN` in column 'Country', group by 'Name' and convert to list then join the sum of 'Price':

```
>>> df.melt(['Name', 'Price'], value_name='Country') \
      .dropna(subset=['Country']).groupby('Name')['Country'] \
      .apply(list).to_frame() \
      .join(df.groupby('Name')['Price'].sum().rename('TotalCost'))

                       Country  TotalCost
Name
Anna   [Sweden, Peru, Iceland]         60
Peter       [Italy, Venezuela]         45
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate `country` and `cost` separately and then combine results:

```
cost = data.Price.groupby(data.Name).sum().rename('TotalCost')
countries = (
  data.melt('Name', ['Country1', 'Country2'], value_name='Countries')
   .dropna()
   .groupby('Name')
   .Countries
   .agg(list))

pd.concat([countries, cost], 1).reset_index()

#    Name                Countries  TotalCost
#0   Anna  [Sweden, Peru, Iceland]         60
#1  Peter       [Italy, Venezuela]         45
```